# Jquery Issue - Drop down list does NOT show from iPhone/Mobile Devices

Tags: iphone, jquery, drop-down-menu

When I see my website http://www.jazzheaven.com from my iPhone: the 2 DROP-DOWNS do NOT work from the iPhone.

The 2 drop-downs are called:
'Choose Your Instrument' 
and further below 
'Click here to Choose Your Instrument'

My Wordpress developer said this is a 2-min job for somebody who understands JQUERY.
Problem being: he & I don't know jQuery.

2ND QUESTION: would fixing this solve it for IPHONES and ANDROIDS and iPADS?

Any pointers very much appreciated.

Note: I am not a techie. I understand HTML and Wordpress backends, but do not know CSS or jquery or javascript.
But I CAN follow specific instructions! ;)

Thanks in advance!

Falk

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://jquerymobile.com